# 18.04: Why this command doesn't work?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash

Sorry for this stupid question, but I spent a time to figure out!!

`#! /bin/bash
a=/etc
cd $a`

Normally, if I assign value for `$a` variable and then `cd $a`, it works. But when I create a separate file - it doesn't!

Why does it happen like this?

Comment: It probably *does* work - but not in the way that you imagine. See [Why doesn't “cd” work in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: @k7aay Please do not add Ubuntu version to title (especially) when the version is not important to the question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing your script using `#!/bin/bash` which launches the new `bash` session invisible for you and changes its directory to `$a` and then exits. You just don't see it.

To achieve what you want, I've slightly modified your script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
a="/etc/"
cd $a
echo $a

$ chmod +x test.sh
```

And executed it using a `.` dot before script (or `source` keyword). It executes script inside of the current bash session:

Result:

```
user@ubuntu:~/test$ . test.sh 
/etc/
user@ubuntu:/etc$
```