# Move to folder without using "exec"

Tags: scripts, zsh

In my VM, my projects are at /var/www/vhosts/projectname/httpdocs/.
When I boot the machine, I start at /home/vagrant/.

I created a script that instantly takes me to the project I want. The problem is, the script uses exec and creates a new session every time I use it.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "No project specified"
   exit 1
fi

cd /var/www/vhosts/"$1"/httpdocs/ || exit

echo "---------------------"
echo "Project: $1"
echo "  https://$1.vm/"
echo "  https://$1.vm/typo3"
echo "---------------------"

exec zsh
```

Is there another way to set my current path without creating a new session?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a script? Why not write a function and put everything except the `exec zsh` in it?

Comment: ..... and change all exit to return ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script indeed runs in a subshell, where the current directory is changed. This environment is killed when the script is ended. Opening an interactive shell (`exec zhs`) is needed to interact with the modified environment, which opens yet another subshell than the one your script is running in.

Using a **shell function** may be most suited for what you want to do.

```
changedir () {
   cd "$1"
   echo "Project: $1"
}
```

Include such function in your `~/.zshrc` file (`.bashrc` for bash users). When you exit then reopen the terminal, the command `changedir` will be available.

Alternatively, you should **source your script** rather than executing it. Also that could be implemented rather elegantly by defining an alias:

```
alias changedir='source <pathname of your script>'
```

Also an alias definition should be included in `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bashrc`) to be persistent. Similar to the previous approach, a command `changedir` becomes available that autocompletes with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

For a more general use case, where you simply want to switch easily to some directories deep in the tree, see various more options [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/481733/558158).

Comment: @steeldriver right you are, and wrong I was. Probably a shell function is most suited for this job, which I now included in the answer.