# Can't cd to path variable in simple bash script

Tags: bash, cd-command

I checked similar questions and tried the answers given, no luck there.

I'm using WSL and trying to do what ought to be simple.  Take a windows path and format it, letting me cd to that directory with this script, let's call it cdw.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_path="$1"

# Replace backslashes with forward slashes
new_path="${input_path//\\//}"

# Replace drive letter with linux mount path
new_path="${new_path/Z:/\/mnt\/z}"

echo "$new_path"
cd "$new_path"
```

However, trying `./cdw.sh 'Z:\test'` echoed the expected $new_path but does not cd there:

```
user1: /mnt/z $ ./cdw.sh 'Z:\test'
/mnt/z/test
user1: /mnt/z $
```

Is there something really simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't "cd" work in a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script runs in a subshell. Changing a directory in a subshell doesn't propagate to the parent shell.

Either source the script

```
. csw.sh 'X:\test'
```

or use a function instead of a script (declare it in your `.bashrc` file if you want it to exist every time):

```bash
csw() {
...  # The code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the current directory **inside a script**, the current directory **outside the script** will not change, as the script is run by a separate instance of the shell.

Instead of simply **running** your script, try to **source** it; then it will be executed in the current instance of the shell, without spawning a new one.

Type:

```
. ./cdw.sh 'Z:\test'
```

(yes, the `.` at the beginning of the line **is a command**). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wslpath` from WSL then there is no need to convert your path.

```
Usage:
    -a    force result to absolute path format
    -u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
    -w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
    -m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with '/' instead of '\'

EX: wslpath 'c:\users'
```

Example:

```
cd $(/usr/bin/wslpath 'Z:\test')
```